# How can I apply a Gradle plugin to itself?

Tags: gradle

I have a Gradle plugin which codifies a collection of checks to perform on the codebase. I would like the plugin itself to be subject to the same checks.

**Attempt 1**

I found part of a solution [here](https://gist.github.com/johnrengelman/9a20697b2246a9bfaca2), which essentially tries to use `buildSrc` to produce a plugin which can then be applied from the main project.

This gives me an error someone else had also seen:

```
No signature of method: GradlePlugins.buildscript() is applicable for argument types: (GradlePlugins$_run_closure1) values: [GradlePlugins$_run_closure1@2e7cad0f]
```

**Attempt 2**

This was adapted from a second suggestion in the thread:

```
apply plugin: new GroovyScriptEngine(
        [ file('src/main/java').absolutePath,
          file('src/main/groovy').absolutePath,
          file('src/main/resources').absolutePath ].toArray(new String[0]),
        this.class.classLoader)
        .loadScriptByName('acme/plugins/CommonPlugin.groovy')
```

But it seems like it can't find classes in the same package as the plugin:

```
Caused by: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: CheckStringsExtension for class: acme.plugins.CommonPlugin
```

**Attempt 3**

There was a comment on the other gist suggesting that it might not work if the plugin script contains a package declaration, so I also tried making a trivial wrapper:

```
import acme.plugins.CommonPlugin
import org.gradle.api.Plugin
import org.gradle.api.Project

class SelfApplyBootstrap implements Plugin<Project> {
    @Override
    void apply(Project project) {
        new CommonPlugin().apply(project);
    }
}
```

And then:

```
apply plugin: new GroovyScriptEngine(
        [ file('src/main/java').absolutePath,
          file('src/main/groovy').absolutePath,
          file('src/main/resources').absolutePath ].toArray(new String[0]),
        this.class.classLoader)
        .loadScriptByName('SelfApplyBootstrap.groovy')
```

But I still get the same error:

```
Caused by: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: CheckStringsExtension for class: acme.plugins.CommonPlugin
```